# SocketAsyncResult.CheckIfThrowDelayedException () System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Network subsystem is down in Xamarin.Android app

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, httpclient

I am working on a Xamarin.Android App development. The HTTP calls work fine when the app is in the foreground. But I recently observed that when the app is in background and then brought to foreground after 10-15 minutes, '**SocketAsyncResult.CheckIfThrowDelayedException ()
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Network subsystem is down**'.

**Stack Trace:**

```
HttpClientHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
HttpClient.SendAsyncWorker (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption completionOption, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
ASAPService.GetBookingDetails (System.String bookingID)
TrackViewModel.GetBookingStatus (System.String bookingDetails)
TrackActivity.<InitializeLocalVariables>b__46_0 (System.Object e)
AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_1 (System.Object state)
QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context (System.Object state)
ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem ()
ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch ()
_ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback ()
```

I tried using the ModernHttpClient after seeing some posts but then I get ''**NativeMessageHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Java.IO.IOException: timeout**' exception.'

I changed the HTTP Client implementation to **Android** and SSL/TLS implementation to 'Native TLS 1.2+' in the project properties. But nothing helped.

This the code that gets called when the app comes to foreground.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

string Url = String.Format(BASE_ASAP_CUSTOMER_URL + AppConstants.BookingStatus + "AppConstants.BookingParam", bookingID);
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AppGlobal.Token);

using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(Url))
 using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
 {
  string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  var bookingStatus =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BookingStatusEntity(result);

return bookingStatus;
```

Comment: i have the same problem. do you have any progress on this yet?

Comment: in my case it didnt help but try this also https://medium.com/@anna.domashych/httpclient-and-proxy-76835c784eab

Comment: @batmaci I was using a single instance of HttpClient for all the Get and Post requests which is actually the right approach to follow. But I tried creating a new instance of HttpClient for all requests and disposed the object after receiving the response. That might not be a good way but somehow I am not seeing the exception now

Comment: i am also doing it this was disposing using an using block but i see  that problem sometimes. i think that there is nothing wrong with disposing and recreating. there is a big debate about this issue. some supports single instance other says now. i have tried both and i found out that creating instance is more efficient. there are some caching effects on single instance.

Comment: sometimes "localhost" will tell the Android emulator to connect back to itself and not to your local server. Can you try the same issue with a public IP?